# Find indices of a value in 2d matrix

Tags: python, optimization, matrix

I have a matrix of the form,

```
mymatrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

I want to the get the index of, say for example, 9 which is at (2,2).

What I have tried to do so far.

```
for i,j in enumerate(mymatrix):
   for k,l in enumerate(j):
     if l==9:
         print i,k
```

Is there a better way of doing the same. Optimization,  anyone? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want all of the locations that the value appears at, you can use the following list comprehension with `val` set to whatever you're searching for

```
[(index, row.index(val)) for index, row in enumerate(mymatrix) if val in row]
```

for example:

```
>>> mymatrix=[[1,2,9],[4,9,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> val = 9
>>> [(index, row.index(val)) for index, row in enumerate(mymatrix) if val in row]
[(0, 2), (1, 1), (2, 2)]
```

**EDIT**

It's not really true that this gets all occurrences, it will only get the first occurrence of the value in a given row.

Comment: That does the trick, these days, I am trying to learn more on the optimisation part? How do I determine the complexity of this code? Generators are fast. That is something I am looking at too..:)

Comment: Have you actually timed how fast this code is compared to OP's code?

Comment: @Blender, I am slightly slow at timing. Still learning the basics..! Any pointers there, I will be really grateful!

Comment: This will iterate over the sublist where it's found twice. Technically, complexity is worse than OP's code but in reality, speed would depend on C implementation so you'd have to time it. For long lists I would think this would be worse.

Comment: @Ryan Haining, Suppose if I want to break of the loop at the first instance of finding my value, how do I do that with your code?

Comment: @Blender the list comprehension is faster for collecting all of the locations in a list

Comment: @Jared yeah I realized the tie complexity of that, and the dependence on implementations, either way I don't think the difference is significant.

Comment: @RyanHaining: But have you tested it with something like the `timeit` module?

Comment: @Anuk if all you're concerned with is the first appearance then you're good with what you have

Comment: @Blender yes, it's about 32% faster than iterating through with `for`s and appending each occurrence to a list

Answer (score 14):

If you convert mymatrix to a numpy array you can jsut use numpy.where to return the indices:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> mymatrix=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> a = np.array(mymatrix)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b = np.where(a==9)
>>> b
(array([2]), array([2]))
>>> mymatrix=[[1,2,3],[9,5,6],[7,8,9]]
>>> a = np.array(mymatrix)
>>> a
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [9, 5, 6],
       [7, 8, 9]])
>>> b = np.where(a==9)
>>> b
(array([1, 2]), array([0, 2]))
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a benchmark of all the answers posted so far including two of my own. I think you may find the results useful, enlightening, and maybe even surprising. `;¬)`

Note I've put the target value to middle of matrix to simulate its average location if the data are random in an effort to level the playing field (a little bit) for algorithms that stop as soon it's is found — the comparison still isn't really fair, however.

Runs under both Python 2 & 3.

**Update** - Added answers that have been posted after last update to this one.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
import sys
from textwrap import dedent
import timeit

EXECUTIONS = 1000000  # Number of times each algorithm is executed per timing run.
TIMINGS = 3  # Number of timing runs.

SETUP = dedent("""
    # Make accessible in algorithms.
    from __main__ import np
    mymatrix=[[1,2,3], [4,9,6], [7,8,5]]  # Target value in middle.
    val = 9  # Target value.
""")

algorithms = {
    "user2459905 (OP) - all occurrences": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences
        found = []
        for i,j in enumerate(mymatrix):
           for k,l in enumerate(j):
             if l==val:
                 found.append((i,k))
    """),

    "ayush thakur (fixed) - all occurrences": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences
        found = []
        for i, e in enumerate(mymatrix):
            for j, ee in enumerate(e):
                if val == ee:  # Fixed.
                    found.append((i, j))
    """),


    "martineau #1 - all occurrences": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences
        width = len(mymatrix[0])
        found = []
        posn = 0
        for row in mymatrix:
            if val not in row:
                posn += width
            else:
                for col in row:
                    if col == val:
                        found.append((posn // width, posn % width))
                    posn += 1
    """),

    "martineau #2 - all occurrences": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences
        width = len(mymatrix[0])
        found = []
        posn = 0
        for row in mymatrix:
            if val in row:
                for y,col in enumerate(row):
                    if col == val:
                        found.append((posn // width, y))
            posn += width
    """),

    "mmtauqir - first occurrence": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences
        matrix_dim = len(mymatrix[0])
        item_index = 0
        for row in mymatrix:
            for i in row:
                if i == val:
                    break
                item_index += 1
            if i == val:
                break
        found = (int(item_index / matrix_dim), item_index % matrix_dim)
    """),

    "rtrwalker - all occurrences using numpy": dedent("""
        # finds all occurrences using numpy
        a = np.array(mymatrix)  # Convert mymatrix to a numpy array.
        found = np.where(a==val)
    """),

    "Ryan Haining - first occurrence (per row)": dedent("""
        # finds first occurrence in each row
        found = [(index, row.index(val)) for index, row in enumerate(mymatrix)
                                            if val in row]
    """),

}


# Benchmark algorithms
timings = [
        (label, min(timeit.repeat(algorithms[label], setup=SETUP,
                                  repeat=TIMINGS, number=EXECUTIONS)))
            for label in algorithms
    ]

# Display metrics.
longest = max(len(timing[0]) for timing in timings)  # Length of longest label.

print('Fastest to slowest execution speeds with {}-bit Python {}.{}.{}'.format(
        64 if sys.maxsize > 2**32 else 32, *sys.version_info[:3]))
print('  with numpy version {}'.format(np.version.full_version),
      '-> {:,d} executions, best of {:,d})'.format(EXECUTIONS, TIMINGS))
print()

ranked = sorted(timings, key=lambda t: t[1])  # sort by speed (fastest first)
for timing in ranked:
    print("{:>{width}} : {:.6f} secs, rel speed {rel:6.3f}x".format(
          timing[0], timing[1], rel=timing[1]/ranked[0][1], width=longest))
```

Results:

```
Fastest to slowest execution speeds with 32-bit Python 2.7.18
  with numpy version 1.16.6 -> 1,000,000 executions, best of 3)

              mmtauqir - first occurrence : 0.667560 secs, rel speed  1.000x
Ryan Haining - first occurrence (per row) : 0.694786 secs, rel speed  1.041x
           martineau #1 - all occurrences : 0.752011 secs, rel speed  1.127x
           martineau #2 - all occurrences : 0.929674 secs, rel speed  1.393x
   ayush thakur (fixed) - all occurrences : 1.541785 secs, rel speed  2.310x
       user2459905 (OP) - all occurrences : 1.544341 secs, rel speed  2.313x
  rtrwalker - all occurrences using numpy : 3.334727 secs, rel speed  4.995x


Fastest to slowest execution speeds with 32-bit Python 3.8.8
  with numpy version 1.21.1 -> 1,000,000 executions, best of 3)

              mmtauqir - first occurrence : 0.734707 secs, rel speed  1.000x
Ryan Haining - first occurrence (per row) : 0.749999 secs, rel speed  1.021x
           martineau #2 - all occurrences : 0.820354 secs, rel speed  1.117x
           martineau #1 - all occurrences : 0.880883 secs, rel speed  1.199x
       user2459905 (OP) - all occurrences : 1.436644 secs, rel speed  1.955x
   ayush thakur (fixed) - all occurrences : 1.638413 secs, rel speed  2.230x
  rtrwalker - all occurrences using numpy : 5.713464 secs, rel speed  7.777x
```

Comment: That is really interesting to know. Even the testing technique is really interesting.!

Answer (score 2):

You could do this instead of using enumerate. NOT sure at all if this is any faster.

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]
needle = 9

matrix_dim = len(matrix[0])
item_index = 0
for row in matrix:
    for i in row:
        if i == needle:
            break
        item_index += 1
    if i == needle:
        break

print(int(item_index / matrix_dim), item_index % matrix_dim)
```

This will take exactly time `i * dim(matrix) + (j+1)` where the result of the above is `i j` which could be `O(n^2)` in the worst case.

Comment: +1 This is the fastest according to benchmark performed in my answer, although it stops after it finds a single occurrence. The only thing faster I found was in-lining the code to check every possible position in the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

**This Can Work for Any Dimensional Array**

```
a = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3) + 10
x=a.flatten().tolist()
index=x.index(11) # (11) it the item i want to search for it's index
np.unravel_index(index,a.shape)
```

**Output:**

```
array([[10, 11, 12],
       [13, 14, 15]])
(0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to find the index of all the occurrence of a val or character in a 2d list, this code may help you and it's readable. Tnq.

```
for i, e in enumerate(board):
    for j, ee in enumerate(e):
        if 'd' in ee:
            print(i, j)
```

you can find multiple occurrences too.

Comment: Assuming you intended the OP's `mymatrix` to be the `board`, this doesn't work because the elements of the matrix are integers — so using something like the `if 'd' in ee:` isn't suitable.