# How to find all the indices of all the elements in a 2d matrix using Python?

Tags: python

I have a multidimensional matrix where I want to find the indices of all the elements in the matrix in the form `(i,j)`. Oh and unfortunately i cannot use the numpy module. So, codes without 'numpy' would be much appreciated guys.

The matrix is:

```
[[0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
 [1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
 [1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
 [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0], 
 [5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0], 
 [4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: Yeah surely someone can help if you show up with some code that you have tried to do the same ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find indices of a value in 2d matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385419/find-indices-of-a-value-in-2d-matrix)

Comment: [(index, row.index(val)) for index, row in enumerate(mymatrix) if val in row]

Delgan...this gives only the first occurrence. I want to find all the occurrences. Any help?

Comment: @ZdaR I have given the matrix above in the question. I want to find all the indices of the elements in the matrix. Can you help?

Comment: All indicies of all elements or all indices of elements with a particular value?

Comment: @xnx All the indices of all the individual elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: if you mean a list of all index pairs (for any element) you can do:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(m)) for j in range(len(m[i]))]

[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
...
 (5, 4),
 (5, 5)]
```

For the indexes of nonzero elements, add a conditional:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(len(m)) for j in range(len(m[i])) if m[i][j] != 0]

[(0, 0),
 (0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
...
 (5, 2),
 (5, 3)]
```

You can find the indices of each element with a particular value, `val` with a double list comprehension:

```
m = [[0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
     [1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 5.0, 4.0], 
     [1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0], 
     [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 1.0, 1.0], 
     [5.0, 5.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0], 
     [4.0, 4.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0, 0]]

val = 1.0
[(i, j) for i, row in enumerate(m) for j, v in enumerate(row) if val==v]

[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 0),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 3)]
```

If you're using NumPy (which is good at this sort of thing), you can use `np.where`, which returns a tuple of row and column coordinates that you can (un)zip:

```
list(zip(*np.where(a==1.0)))

[(0, 1),
 (0, 2),
 (0, 3),
 (1, 0),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (2, 0),
 (2, 1),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (2, 5),
 (3, 0),
 (3, 1),
 (3, 2),
 (3, 4),
 (3, 5),
 (4, 2),
 (4, 3),
 (5, 2),
 (5, 3)]
```

Comment: This needs the user to specify the value for 'val' at every instant. Is there a way to get all the indices of all the elements without needing to specify the specific element value?

Comment: Do you mean the nonzero values? The indices of all the elements you can just generate from a pair of loops over the dimensions

Comment: Thanks a lot! @xnx It helped. :)