# How can I loop over true values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, loops, boolean

I have a boolean array in python and I want to do a calculation on the cells where the value is 'true'. Currently I am using a nested for loop to go trough all the cells to find the cells with the true values. However, running the program takes a lot of time. I was wondering wether there is a faster way to do this?

```
for i in range (0,latstep):  
    for j in range (0,lonstep):     
        if coastline[i,j] == True:
        ...
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What are the contents of `coastline`?

Comment: `coastline[i,j]` is invalid

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find indices of a value in 2d matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385419/find-indices-of-a-value-in-2d-matrix)

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! coastline is a 2d boolean array. On the locations were coastline is True I want to do a calculation with other arrays.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, yes thanks! I couldn't find that one

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not sure it will be *faster*, but you can try the different methods with your data and pick the one that works best for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might consider using `concurrent.map()` or similar to process the array elements in parallel. Always assuming there aren't dependencies between
the elements.

Another possibility is maintaining a list of the 'true' values when you initially calculate them:

```
coastlineCache = []

c = foo()
coastline[i][j] = c

if (c):
    coastlineCache.append(c)

// later

for (c in coastlineCache):
    process_true_item(c)
```

If, as you've alluded to above, you need the array indices, cache them as a tuple:

```
coastlineCache = []

c = foo()
coastline[i][j] = c
if (c):
    coastlineCache.append((i, j))

// later

for (c in coastlineCache):
    process_true_item(c[0], c[1]) # e.g. (i, j)
```

Comment: Thanks @JarvisCochrane, this is perfect because I need to use this another time further down the code as well!

Answer (score 0):

You can use nested list comprehensions, each comprehension is slightly faster than a generic for-loop on smaller input sizes:

```
final_list = [[foo(b) for b in i if b] for i in coastline]
```