# How do I merge many binary files as efficiently as possible?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, merge, multiprocessing

I am writing a multi-connection downloader that downloads a single file in 32 parts through 32 processes using `multiprocess` library from UQ Foundation, and I would like to know the most efficient way to merge the parts back into a single file.

The files are 32 continuous blocks of (almost) equal size, with at most 1 byte difference in size, and are named in this formula:

```py
'{0}.{1}.part'.format(filepath, str(i).zfill(2))
```

`filepath` is a `str` representing where the downloaded file should be stored, including name and extension. `i` is an `int` between 0 and 32 (not including 32), then zero-padded into 2 digit `str` to avoid the alphabetical sorting on numerical strings.

The following gets the job done, but is slow and memory-intensive:

```py
with open(filepath, 'wb') as dest:
    for file in files:
        f = open(file, 'rb')
        dest.write(f.read())
        f.close()
        os.remove(file)
```

This is slightly better, but still slow:

```py
BLOCKSIZE = 4096
BLOCKS = 1024
chunk = BLOCKS * BLOCKSIZE
with open(filepath, "wb") as dest:
    for file in files:
        with open(file, "rb") as f:
            data = f.read(chunk)
            while data != b'':
                dest.write(data)
                data = f.read(chunk)
        os.remove(file)
```

(I actually use a variant of the second method using `pathlib` and `mmap` so none of these with clauses, but the basic idea is the same).

Instead I believe using 32 subprocesses to read the contents of the files concurrently then report the data to the parent process and let the parent process write the data to disk would be better, I have 4 CPU cores but these process aren't going to do significant calculations, how can it be done using `multiprocess`?

---

The source and destinations are on the same device, in the same folder, the device is either HDD or SSD and presumably one with NTFS filesystem (mine's a Seagate EXOS 4TB HDD with NTFS with a block size of 4KiB).

The files can be very big (I am going to use it to download "copylefted" "interactive digital art" which can be over 20GiB) and I have only 16GiB RAM and I don't expect any user to have more RAM than 16GiB, so loading entire files into memory isn't feasible.

And I use Windows 10 21H1 and I target Windows 10.

---

My bandwidth is 100mbps or 11.92MiB/s, and I use a VPN because I am in China.

I have observed all download managers I have used download files much faster and more stable than browsers, all of them support multi-connection downloading and support 32 connections per download.

I am aware most browsers support 8 connections per download at most and almost all files are downloaded using a single thread, the main incentive to using multi-connections isn't because it makes your bandwidth bigger, but rather it minimizes the impact of speed throttling, most servers set a quota that a connection can have, and that limit is often much less than bandwidth, using multiple connections the quota will be increased proportional to that multiple, and where I am, you know, the government actively throttles international traffic if not outright interrupt it, and VPN increases latency therefore increases throttling...

Comment: Multiprocessing will potentially be slower because you'll have to allow for possible contention when writing to your output file - i.e. you'll need some kind of locking mechanism. I would have expected your first example to be the fastest possible. Also, I don't see how there would be a huge overhead on memory. Can you explain more about that?

Comment: What is your bottleneck, what is your current best speed, what is your target speed?

Comment: Are your source and destination files on the same device or different ones? What kind of device(s)?

Comment: What speed do you get using the fastest option in the underlying OS? (on Linux, that would probably be `dd` with a suitable `bs` setting)

Comment: Where are you downloading from, and with what bandwidth, that it makes sense to use 32 parallel processes and can outperform an SSD?

Comment: Thank you for editing your question. Your second example will be faster because you won't necessarily acquire all the data from the input file(s). Reading in chunks may help with memory consumption but you need to remember to iterate over the chunked reads until the data stream is exhausted

Comment: What you are doing is I/O-bound, so using concurrency is unlikely to speed it up significantly because that's not where the bottleneck is — and it may in fact slow things down due to the additional overhead using it introduces.

Comment: Arguably, the best way to determine the most efficient way to do something is to compare the speed of various ways of doing it. There's an example of extensible benchmarking framework in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17386771/355230) of mine to an unrelated question that you could easily repurpose and use to answer this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some tests, first you need to download this file: http://ipv4.download.thinkbroadband.com/1GB.zip (direct link) using any download manager you use (it is advised against using browsers for this), it is a file containing exactly 1GiB garbage data specifically for testing purposes, it should have this hash:

5674e59283d95efe8c88770515a9bbc80cbb77cb67602389fd91def26d26aed2

Split the file into 32 chunks (I downloaded the file to D:\downloads\1GB.zip, change as needed):

```py
from pathlib import Path                                                      

i = 0
files = []
with Path('D:/downloads/1GB.zip').open('rb') as f:                            
    while (chunk := f.read(33554432)):
        path = 'D:/1GB.zip.{0}.part'.format(str(i).zfill(2))                                        
        Path(path).write_bytes(chunk)
        files.append(path)
        i += 1
```

My disk is Seagate EXOS 7E8 4TB, connected to SATA III 6.0Gb/s port, its filesystem is NTFS with a cluster size of 4KiB.

I have done the following tests:

Method 1:

```py
with Path('D:/1GB.zip').open('wb') as dest:
    for file in files:
        dest.write(Path(file).read_bytes())
```

Method 2:

```py
BLOCKSIZE = 4096
BLOCKS = 1024
CHUNKSIZE = BLOCKSIZE * BLOCKS

with Path('D:/1GB.zip').open('wb') as dest:
    for file in files:
        with Path(file).open('rb') as f:
            while (segment := f.read(CHUNKSIZE)):
                dest.write(segment)
```

Both methods produce intended result:

```py
import hashlib
HASH = '5674e59283d95efe8c88770515a9bbc80cbb77cb67602389fd91def26d26aed2'

sha = hashlib.sha256()
with Path('D:/1GB.zip').open('rb') as f:
    while (chunk := f.read(1048576)):
        sha.update(chunk)

print(sha.hexdigest() == HASH)
```

On my machine, using timeit magic, the first method takes around 3.25s to complete on average, with observed disk utilization speed reach about 320MiB/s max.

While method 2 takes about 1.25s on average, with observed max speed of 850 MiB/s.

Theoretically SATA III has a bandwidth of 6.0Gb/s which translates to 750MB/s in SI decimal units, which then translates to 715.2557373046875MiB/s in binary units, which then is reduced by 8b/10b encoding to a maximum transfer speed of 600MB/s which is 572.20458924375MiB/s in binary units.

The first method has a max write speed of around 320MiB/s with an average speed of 315.076923MiB/s, while the second method has a max write speed of around 850MiB/s and average speed of 819.2MiB/s far exceeding the theoretical SATA 3.0 limit, it seems my HDD really outperforms the theoretical SATA bandwidth and I have absolutely squuezed more performance than I could have imagined, it seems I really have reached the limit and using multiprocessing won't help, but I trully believe using mmap will make things even faster.

But that is not the case with downloading, because network bandwidth is far less than HDD bandwidth, and most of the time that bandwidth isn't fully utilized during downloads and most servers limit how much bandwidth each connection can have, having more connections means you can utilize more of your bandwidth and one bad connection doesn't affect the others, using multiconnection will definitely speed up downloads.

Comment: My interpretation of the OP's question is that the download isn't the issue - it's the merge of the separate files that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

For the merge part, I would suggest to not split the files at the first place, you can create and reserve a big file with the size of the main file, and then logically split it into pieces and assign a start byte for every thread.
For example let's say you have a 4GB file and 4 thread, first thread start at byte 0, second start at byte 1024^3 (1GB) and third at 2GB and so on. this way you don't have to deal with merging the files.
I should also mention that there's some synchronization problem with this solution which should be manage.

But in overall, I think that the bottleneck in your example is more related to your bandwidth rather than the storage. and I don't think making 32 process for downloading a file makes it faster.

Comment: The SI unit for gigabytes is **GB** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte, whereas **Gb** refers to gigabits https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit